# Change default view in VS 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to set change a  default View in MVC3 when debbuging the project in Visual Studio 2010.

As soon I hit F5, The default View it opens is Localhost/Home/Index.

Where is it being set, How do I update it?

Can anyone shed some light on this please? It is not straight forward(for me though).

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is changed your default `MapRoute` parameters.  Typically, this is what you'll see *by default* as your `Default` route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", 
                  action = "Index", 
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional }); // Parameter defaults
```

Just change the `controller` property and the `action` property to what you want your default to be.  For instance, you could do:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "AnotherController", 
                  action = "aDifferentAction", 
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional }); // Parameter defaults
```

All that is changed here is the `controller` and `action` properties.  Now when you browse to just the qualified name, it will go to your `AnotherController.aDifferentAction()` method, instead of the `HomeController.Index()` method.

#### Explanation

The reason why it defaults to `Home.Index()`, is because that is the first matched route when you have empty route parameters for `controller` and `action`.  By changing these defaults in the `MapRoute()` call, you are telling routing that if nothing is there for the route parameters, go to `AnotherController.aDifferentAction()` action method.

As long as this is the first route, you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default page in the Routes table as [Shark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596075/shark) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820344/384808), but something tells me this probably isn't really what you're looking for. If you just want to debug a specific page, right-click the view and select 'View In Browser' from the context menu.