# How to modify ASP MVC default view name associated to a controller action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to modify the ASP MVC default view name associated to a controller action method.

Here is my Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

As the View() method called without viewName parameter the MVC framwork will look for the view Views/Home/Index.cshtml (and similars)

What I would like to achieve is to look for Views/ThemeA/Home/Index.cshtml or Views/ThemeB/Home/Index.cshtml depending on a global setting.

Please do not recommend me to pass the view name as parameter. The whole point is to be transparent to the Controllers.

Thx in advance

Comment: Maybe this post can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820315/change-default-view-in-vs-2010

Comment: I don't think so... My question nothing to do with the _routing_. Thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write you own ViewEngine:

http://theshravan.net/blog/configure-the-views-search-locations-in-asp-net-mvc/

Don´tbe scared, just inherit from the standard engine and extend the search locations...